# C - printf shows unexpected output

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am kind of new to programming and wanted to write a program to read 5 numbers and add them. this is how it looked like.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a,b,c,d,e,sum;

    printf("Enter the 5 numbers\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e);

    sum=a+b+c+d+e;
    printf("Sum of entered integers is %d\n,sum");

    return 0;
}
```

I haven't reached loops till now. So, why isn't my program not giving the correct results? It showed no compiling error to me. But when I input the numbers 1,2,3,4,5, it gave some gibberish result as 2752264!!!

Comment: Why didn't you check the return value of `scanf` which tells you how many variables were successfully populated?

Comment: You might want to check the printf statement where your are printing "sum".

Comment: How you are giving your input?

Comment: Nothingiswrong,it'sok. Justcheckthe"charactersarewheretheyhavetobe,perhapsthelackofwhitespaceisthecausethatyoudidn'tseethat.

Comment: @Bathsheba could you please clarify what you mean? i didnt get you...

Comment: Do you get build errors? Because then you should not be able to get an executable program that you can run. Perhaps you get *warnings*? Also, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then *edit your question* to show possible errors and warnings (if that's what you ask about) or the input and actual and expected output (if that's what you're asking about).

Comment: Also, look at where the rabbits ears are in the `printf`.

Comment: `gcc -Wall` and you'll see the error.

Comment: By the way, do you enter the input as you show it, *with* the commas?

Comment: Any IDE with syntax highlighting or even here, on SO will show what is wrong right away. Colors, they matter.

Answer (score 5):

Your printf statement syntax is wrong.

Use `printf("Sum of entered integers is %d\n", sum);`

instead of `printf("Sum of entered integers is %d\n,sum");`

You need to specify what variable value you have to print for %d inside the printf statement and it has to be outside the quotes. Right now in your case you are not specifying any variable as everything is inside the quotes. So it is taking garbage value.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks. Yeah, that did the job.